# While re-directing top output to file can see special characters

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to redirect output of a top command, but I could see extra special character in file.

```
top -n 10 | grep --color=auto -i influx  >> perf.txt
```

in file

```
(B[m21942 root      20   0  832268 286408  38792 S   5.9  0.9 478:07.97 influxd                                                                                                                                                               (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m21942 root      20   0  832268 286408  38792 S   8.3  0.9 478:08.22 influxd                                                                                                                                                               (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m21942 root      20   0  832268 286408  38792 S   0.7  0.9 478:08.25 influxd                                                                                                                                                               (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m21942 root      20   0  832268 286408  38792 S   3.0  0.9 478:08.34 influxd                                                                                                                                                               (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m21942 root      20   0  832268 286408  38792 S   0.3  0.9 478:08.35 influxd                                                                                                                                                               (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m21942 root      20   0  832268 286408  38792 S   0.3  0.9 478:08.36 influxd                                                                                                                                                               (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m21942 root      20   0  832268 286408  38792 S   3.3  0.9 478:08.46 influxd                                                                                                                                                               (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m21942 root      20   0  832268 286408  38792 S   0.3  0.9 478:08.47 influxd                                                                                                                                                               (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m21942 root      20   0  832268 286408  38792 S   0.3  0.9 478:08.48 influxd                                                                                                                                                               (B[m[39;49m[K
```

How can we avoid above special characters?

Answer (score 2):

The `top` command has batch mode (-b), which will eliminate cursor control sequences from the output. As per man page, it make it easier to parse the output by other programs.

Also, consider eliminating the `--color` from the grep, which will introduce control sequences to highlight the matches

```
top -b -n10 | grep influx >> perf.txt
```